# I want to display the list of category and the sub category of each parent category right under from two different tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, categories

my tables

```
tbl_company(id,user_id,name,description)
tbl_project(id,name,company_id)
```

In controller:

```
public function manage() {
  $this->load->model('company/companymodel');
  $companys = $this->companymodel->get();
  $companydata = array();
  foreach ($companys as $key => $company) {
    $companydata[$key] = $company;
    //$this->load->model('projectmodel');
    $Projects = $this->projectmodel->get($company->company_id);
    //debug($Projects);
    $companydata[$key]->projects = $Projects;
  }
  //debug($companydata);
  $data = array(
      'content' => 'project/manage',
      'companydata' => $companydata,
    );
  //debug($data);
  $this->load->view('dashboard_wrapper',$data);
}
```

In View:

```
<div class="box-content">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
  <?php foreach( $companydata as $company){ ?>
    <h3><?php echo $company->company_name;  ?></h3>
    <?php foreach($company->projects as $project) { ?>
      <li><?php echo $project->name;  ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>            
</div>
```

i need to display in view related projects to the related company:

- company1

  - project1
  - project2
  - project3
- company2

  - project1
  - project2
  - project3

Comment: Please be more precise on the problem that you encounter. What did you try so far?

Comment: @pyStarter you can check my errors in this [link](http://teamhub.atsnepal.com/index.php/project/manage) it comes with following errors..it doesn't shows the related projects to the related company but it comes with all projects. the line no: 50 error is                                                     $Projects = $this->projectmodel->get($company->company_id); which is  in the above controller.